# Integer corrupt in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I have this strange behavior in my rendering process. I'm passing an 32-bit unsigned integer as an attribute to my shader. The vertex-shader forwards this attribute as a flat uint to the fragmentshader.

In the fragment shader I do a comparison. In my case send in 1u and I compare with 1u. This doesn't generate true. Instead my value compared to

```
0x3F800000
```

generates true.

So, somehow my initial 32-bit value:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001
```

Has become:

```
0011 1111 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

All I'm doing is this:

Vertex:

```
layout(location = 3) in uint in_index
flat out uint v_index;
v_index = in_index;
```

Fragment:

```
if (v_index == 0x3F800000u){discard;}
```

And all fragments are discarded. I'm using core 330.

And by the way, I've used floats and shorts and they all work fine.

Comment: It may be the case that you passed the integer data to your vertex attribute incorrectly. This is a common problem if you use `glVertexAttribPointer (...)` instead of `glVertexAttribIPointer (...)`.

Answer (score 1):

@Andon M. Coleman solved it for me!

use glVertexAttribIPointer (...) instead of glVertexAttribPointer (...).